# Inequality exercise with greater integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In one book I found the following exercise

$\lfloor  \left | x \right | \rfloor \leq \frac{x-1}{3}$

To solve it makes $\frac{x-1}{3}=n\in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore it uses the property $\lfloor \left | x \right | \rfloor \leq n\Leftrightarrow x< n+1$,$n\in \mathbb{Z}$ coming to the solution set $\left \{ -2,-5,-8,... \right \}$.

I think this is not the right solution, for example the inequality is true if $x=-3$ or $x=-3.4$, that is,

What is the process to solve this type of inequations that have greater integer?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does $[y]$ denote the greatest integer less than $y$?

Comment: Istn't $[|{-3.4}|]=[3.4]=3$?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $[|x|] \le (x-1)/3$ for all real $x$? All integers $x$? Or are you trying to find all values $x$ that satisfy the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $\,\lfloor  \left | x \right | \rfloor \leq \dfrac{x-1}{3}\,$ does not hold for any real values $\,x \in \mathbb{R}\,$:

- if $\,x \lt 0\,$ then $\,\dfrac{x-1}{3} \lt 0 \le \lfloor  \left | x \right | \rfloor\,$
- if $\,x \ge 0\,$ then using $\require{cancel}\,x \lt \lfloor x \rfloor + 1\,$ it follows that $\,\dfrac{x-1}{3} \lt \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \cancel{1} - \cancel{1}}{3} = \dfrac{\lfloor  x \rfloor}{3} \le \lfloor  x \rfloor\,$

Comment: The given inequality is true for $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, for example $x=-5.7$

Comment: $x=-5.7$, $\left [ \left | -5,7 \right | \right ]=-6$, $-6\leq \frac{-5.7-1}{3}=-2,33$

Comment: @VictorHuuancaSullca No, $\lfloor \left| -5.7\right| \rfloor = \lfloor 5.7 \rfloor = 5\,$. If you mean something else by that notation, please edit the question and clarify.